Who was with the three friends of Daniel in the fire?
Daniel 3:24-25 KJV‬

24 Then Nebuchadnezzar the king was astonied, and rose up in haste, and spake, and said unto his counselors, Did not we cast three men bound into the midst of the fire? They answered and said unto the king, True, O king. 25 He answered and said, Lo, I see four men loose, walking in the midst of the fire, and they have no hurt; and the form of the fourth is like the Son of God.


Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

My first point, the text does not explicitly identify the fourth figure. The fourth figure in the fiery furnace with Shadrach, Meshach, and Abednego is described as having the appearance of a "divine being" or “a son of the gods” in various translations.
What are some interpretations then?

It is often interpreted as an angel. For example, in Daniel 3:28 the
same personage is called an angel of God by Nebuchadnezzar.
[1]
It could be a theophany, an appearance of God in the Old Testament.
Some suggest this could be a pre-incarnate
appearance of Christ, hence the phrase “like the Son of God” in the
King James Version and New King James.

This being said, Nebuchadnezzar, who was a polytheist, might have interpreted the figure "as a son of the gods (plural) rather than “like the Son of God” (singular)

I appreciate that you provided various interpretations rather than only what you personally might believe. Otherwise this becomes an "opinion-based" question.
